# Steam game crashing upon startup

Tags: steam

I'm running Ubuntu 21 via VirtualBox on my macOS.  Steam runs just fine.  However, when I click "Play" for a game (in this case, Civilization V), the game never starts.

Here's the output from the terminal:

```
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'\0
Game process added : AppID 8930 "/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 7578, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 7] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Game process removed: AppID 8930 "/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/daniel/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 7578 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

Comment: I suspect the game won't run in VB, because of GPU limitations in a VM. Why don't you install Steam to MacOS?

Comment: Any game or game with certain requirements?

Comment: Some simple games may run, but Civ V is heavy enough. You can install Steam to Mac.

Comment: That's true.  However, the original reason I wanted to load Steam on my VM is to run 32-bit games like Borderlands Pre-Sequel.

Comment: Civ V won't run for sure in a VM.

Comment: Why is that?  Because of the graphics requirement?